# How to achieve this hover effect using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

What I am doing here is when I hover over the wrapper section an overlay is rendered and clicking in that overlay change the CSS of input border and remove readonly attribute of input and vice versa.

I have gone through many google searches and tutorials about animations and DOM manipulation using AngularJS. But I am so not able to achieve the following effect in the snippet. Actually I have used this effect in my project using javascript and jquery and now I want to migrate to angular and I find that doing jquery DOM manipulation in angular is not a good practice. I am not being able to get this effect using angular. Can anyone help me do this the angular way?

```js
$('body').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.overlay').fadeIn();
  $('.wrapper input').css('border','none');
  $('.wrapper input').attr('readonly', false)
});

$('.overlay').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).fadeOut();
  $(this).parent().find('input').css('border','1px solid grey');
  $(this).parent().find('input').attr('readonly', false);
  stop();
});


function stop(){
   $('.wrapper input').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .overlay{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
  z-index: 10;
}

.wrapper .overlay:hover{
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
} 

.wrapper input{
  border: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <input type="text" value="hello world" readonly>
  <input type="text" value="hello world" readonly>
  <input type="text" value="hello world" readonly>
  <input type="text" value="hello world" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to do any DOM manipualtion, you can do it in directive.

Comment: I have been trying to do it but it so not happening. Could you please help me through getting this effect in angular way?

Comment: Instead, write all the `css` you want to apply in a class. And add, remove that class. This might not be the best solution. I think you can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to trigger the border + readonly in angular < 2 you need this

https://plnkr.co/edit/yHtiIyISidBscAKdCWiQ?p=preview

I don't think you really need any jQuery DOM manipulation in this case.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-class="{bordered: bordered}">
  <div class="overlay" ng-click="triggerBorders()" ng-if="!bordered"></div>
  <input type="text" value="hello world" ng-readonly="!bordered" />
  <input type="text" value="hello world" ng-readonly="!bordered" />
  <input type="text" value="hello world" ng-readonly="!bordered" />
  <input type="text" value="hello world" ng-readonly="!bordered" />
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppController', AppController);

function AppController($scope) {
  $scope.bordered = false;
  $scope.triggerBorders = function() {
    $scope.bordered = !$scope.bordered;
  }
}
```

**Styles**

```
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .overlay{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
  z-index: 10;
}

.wrapper .overlay:hover{
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
} 

.wrapper input{
  border: none
}

.wrapper.bordered input{
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

Comment: and how do I get to same state as in the beginning if I clicked outside those input boxes?

Comment: just use any other event to trigger the same triggerBorders(). It can be a click, a hover.... Anything.

For example:  ng-click="triggerBorders()" on a wrapper. It can also be on a body if you move ng-app and controller initiation higher in DOM

Comment: But can we do something like stopPropagation of jquery in angular?

Comment: how is it related to your previous question about an initial state?

Comment: So this solution didn't help you?

Comment: Yup it did. Thanks